# AngularJS route provider not loading templateUrl

Tags: angularjs

I am currently studying AngularJS and as I am learning I am trying to implement.

Currently, I am studying the routeProvider aspect. I have tried to incude what I have learned but for some reason the route provider isnt loading the required templateUrl.

Please see below.

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/second">SECOND</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div ng-view></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var myapp = angular.module("myapp", ['ngRoute']);
    myapp.config(function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'main.html',
        controller: 'maincontroller'
      })
      .when('/second', {
        templateUrl: 'second.html',
        controller: 'maincontroller'
      })
    });

    myapp.controller("maincontroller", ["$scope", function($scope){
      $scope.title1 = "main page";
      $scope.title2 = "second page";
    }])
  </script>
```

When I click on the second li element to try and load the second page, nothing happens. Is anyone able to identify what I am doing wrong here?

I am following the course: **"Learn & Understand AngularJS"** on Udemy.

Comment: Try changeing your `href` attributes to: ` <a href="#/!">HOME</a></li> and <a href="#!second">SECOND</a> `

Answer (score -1):

You can use  routerLink="/second" routerLinkActive = "active"

Like this.

```
<li><a routerLink="/second" routerLinkActive = "active">SECOND</a></li>
```

You also need to have a routes defined in app.component.ts.

Comment: Your answer seems to assume the OP is using Angular, but the OP is using AngularJS.